# class style is not working

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to change the word color which is in class=css to white when I click the 'night' button but it is not working while all the other word color changes as I meant to.

and this is my code

```css
    .css {
      font-weight: bold;
      color: pink;
    }
    #first {
      color: lightblue;
    }
    span {
      font-weight: lighter;
      color: green;
    }
```

```html
    <input type="button" value="night"
    onclick= "
    document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundColor = 'darkblue';
    document.querySelector('body').style.color = 'yellow';
    document.querySelector('.css').style.color = 'white';
    document.querySelector('#first').style.color = 'orange';
    ">
    <input type="button" value="day"
    onclick ="
    document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundColor = 'white';
    document.querySelector('body').style.color = 'black';
    document.querySelector('.css').style.color = 'pink';
    document.querySelector('#first').style.color = 'lightblue';
    ">
    <h1><a href="index.html">WEB</a></h1>
    <h2 style="background-color:lightblue; color:Tomato;">CSS</h2>
    <span id="first" class="css">CSS</span> is a language that describes the style of an HTML document.
    <span class="css">CSS</span>  describes how <span>HTML</span> elements should be displayed.
    This tutorial will teach you <span class="css">CSS</span>  from basic to advanced.
```

Comment: document.querySelector() only gives you the first element that matches the selector. It does not give you the CSS-class to change.

Comment: May I ask why you removed your accept from my answer?

Answer (score 2):

As other has mentioned, the `document.querySelector()` will only select one element, the first it finds, the `document.querySelectorAll()` will find all, still, that is not the best way here.

You should use [event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of inline event handlers, and toggle a class (here done on the `body`) is much more efficient, and the recommended way, than change inline style.

With that it gets as simple as this.

Stack snippet

```js
document.querySelector('input[value="night"]').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('body').classList.add('night');
});
document.querySelector('input[value="day"]').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('body').classList.remove('night');
});
```

```css
.css {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: pink;
}

#first {
  color: lightblue;
}

span {
  font-weight: lighter;
  color: green;
}

body.night {
  background-color: darkblue;
  color: yellow;
}

.night .css {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}

.night #first {
  color: orange;
}

.night span {
  font-weight: lighter;
  color: ;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="night">
<input type="button" value="day">
<h1><a href="index.html">WEB</a></h1>
<h2 style="background-color:lightblue; color:Tomato;">CSS</h2>
<span id="first" class="css">CSS</span> is a language that describes the style of an HTML document.
<span class="css">CSS</span> describes how <span>HTML</span> elements should be displayed. This tutorial will teach you <span class="css">CSS</span> from basic to advanced.
```

---

And you can do this with only one button

```js
document.querySelector('input[type="button"]').addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.value = (this.value == 'Night') ? 'Day' : 'Night';
  document.querySelector('body').classList.toggle('night');
});
```

```css
.css {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: pink;
}

#first {
  color: lightblue;
}

span {
  font-weight: lighter;
  color: green;
}

body.night {
  background-color: darkblue;
  color: yellow;
}

.night .css {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}

.night #first {
  color: orange;
}

.night span {
  font-weight: lighter;
  color: ;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Night">
<h1><a href="index.html">WEB</a></h1>
<h2 style="background-color:lightblue; color:Tomato;">CSS</h2>
<span id="first" class="css">CSS</span> is a language that describes the style of an HTML document.
<span class="css">CSS</span> describes how <span>HTML</span> elements should be displayed. This tutorial will teach you <span class="css">CSS</span> from basic to advanced.
```

Answer (score 0):

`querySelector` only selects a single element, so when you `document.querySelector('.css')` and assign to its style, you're only changing the style of a single element.

Use `querySelectorAll` and `forEach` instead, to iterate over the `css` elements:

```css
.css {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: pink;
}

#first {
  color: lightblue;
}

span {
  font-weight: lighter;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="night" onclick="
    document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundColor = 'darkblue';
    document.querySelector('body').style.color = 'yellow';
    document.querySelectorAll('.css').forEach(elm => elm.style.color = 'white');
    document.querySelector('#first').style.color = 'orange';
    ">
<input type="button" value="day" onclick="
    document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundColor = 'white';
    document.querySelector('body').style.color = 'black';
    document.querySelectorAll('.css').forEach(elm => elm.style.color = 'pink');
    document.querySelector('#first').style.color = 'lightblue';
    ">
<h1><a href="index.html">WEB</a></h1>
<h2 style="background-color:lightblue; color:Tomato;">CSS</h2>
<span id="first" class="css">CSS</span> is a language that describes the style of an HTML document.
<span class="css">CSS</span> describes how <span>HTML</span> elements should be displayed. This tutorial will teach you <span class="css">CSS</span> from basic to advanced.
```

But inline handlers are as bad as `eval` and should be avoided - attach them properly in Javascript, instead, if at all possible:

```js
document.querySelector('input[value="night"]').onclick = () => {
  document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundColor = 'darkblue';
  document.querySelector('body').style.color = 'yellow';
  document.querySelectorAll('.css').forEach(elm => elm.style.color = 'white');
  document.querySelector('#first').style.color = 'orange';
}
document.querySelector('input[value="day"]').onclick = () => {
  document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  document.querySelector('body').style.color = 'black';
  document.querySelectorAll('.css').forEach(elm => elm.style.color = 'pink');
  document.querySelector('#first').style.color = 'lightblue';
}
```

```css
.css {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: pink;
}

#first {
  color: lightblue;
}

span {
  font-weight: lighter;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="night">
<input type="button" value="day">
<h1><a href="index.html">WEB</a></h1>
<h2 style="background-color:lightblue; color:Tomato;">CSS</h2>
<span id="first" class="css">CSS</span> is a language that describes the style of an HTML document.
<span class="css">CSS</span> describes how <span>HTML</span> elements should be displayed. This tutorial will teach you <span class="css">CSS</span> from basic to advanced.
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `querySelector` when you are targeting multiple elements. Use `querySelectorAll` instead.

Moreover, I recommand you to separate the `css` from the `js`, like below.

```js
function changeCssClassItemsColor(color) {
  const cssItems = document.querySelectorAll('.css');

  cssItems.forEach(function(item) {
    item.style.color = color;
  });
}

function switchToNight() {
  document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundColor = 'darkblue';
  document.querySelector('body').style.color = 'yellow';
  document.querySelector('#first').style.color = 'orange';

  changeCssClassItemsColor('white');
}

function switchToDay() {
  document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  document.querySelector('body').style.color = 'black';
  document.querySelector('#first').style.color = 'lightblue';

  changeCssClassItemsColor('pink');

}
```

```css
.css {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: pink;
}

#first {
  color: lightblue;
}

span {
  font-weight: lighter;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="night" onclick="switchToNight()">

<input type="button" value="day" onclick="switchToDay()">

<h1><a href="index.html">WEB</a></h1>

<h2 style="background-color:lightblue; color:Tomato;">CSS</h2>

<span id="first" class="css">CSS</span> is a language that describes the style of an HTML document.

<span class="css">CSS</span> describes how <span>HTML</span> elements should be displayed. This tutorial will teach you <span class="css">CSS</span> from basic to advanced.
```